# Excluir todos os itens que possuem ao menos um valor Null

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Estou precisando fazer uma query que NÃO retorne os IDs de contratos que possuam QUAISQUER parcelas como Null, no exemplo abaixo eu preciso que ela retorne vazia, pois o contrato de ID 666666 possui ao menos uma parcela null, mesmo que a 3° linha tenha um inteiro.

Remover as linhas null com `not exists` ou `not in` não seria problema, mas com esses comandos a query ainda retornaria a 3° linha

```
select contrato.IdContrato as ID, parcela.ValorParcela as Parcela
left join parcelas on parcelas.IdContrato = contrato.IdContrato
where contrato.IdContrato = 666666
```

A query fornece campos como:
**ID     |  Parcela

666666   |  null

666666   |  null

666666   |  200**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arthur, acho que você pode sim utilizar o not exists. Segue sugestão para testes:

```
select contrato.IdContrato as ID, parcela.ValorParcela as Parcela
left join parcelas on parcelas.IdContrato = contrato.IdContrato
where 
    contrato.IdContrato = 666666 and 
    not exists
    (
        select 1 from parcelas as s 
        where 
            s.IdContrato = contrato.IdContrato and
            s.ValorParcela is null
    )
```

Espero que ajude

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar **AND** para satisfazer todas as condições.

Ficaria:

```
where contrato.IdContrato = 666666 and parcela.ValorParcela !=  null
```

Comment: Mas nesse caso ele estaria mantendo a terceira linha ainda, não?